# Pause and play a video in WPF applications

Tags: c#, wpf

I  have recently started working on  C#.

What I want to do is stop a video played in a WPF application after 10 seconds. I know i need a some kind of a timer (DispatcherTimer) but don't know how to use it.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

XAML code:

```
<MediaElement Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top ="40"
 Name="VideoControl" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop"  
 MediaOpened="VideoControl_MediaOpened" Source="c:\users\ayymmoo\documents\visual 
 studio 2010\Projects\play_video\play_video\How I Met Your Mother Season 06 Episode 03 
 - Unfinished.avi">
 </MediaElement>
```

Xaml.cs code

```
void PlayClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VideoControl.Play();
}
void PauseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VideoControl.Pause();
}
void StopClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VideoControl.Stop();
}

private void VideoControl_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

---

i tried to replace my code with the one u defined ...... and it works fine for the first time but when i play again from the pause position it pauses again before 10 seconds and the pause intervals becomes lesser as i play again and again this is the code

```
public void PlayClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    VideoControl.Play();
    var dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoControl.Pause();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

Init of your Timer

```
var  dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,10);
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

Ticked Method foreach interval

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 .... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your timer out of this scope to a private field, initialize it in your constructor and then start the timer in the PlayClick method, but don't forget to stop the timer in dispatcherTimer_Tick method.

I think that the first time you run the timer, it works, then the second time, you create another timer, but the first one is still firing every ten seconds, which then happens to be less than ten seconds after you clicked play the second time.